# Express сервер, проблема с переходом на ссылки

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Всем привет уважаемые господа проблема следующая: Имеется файл express.js где имеется код для перехода между страницами

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

let app = express();
let publicPath = path.join(__dirname,'../Site/ejs');

app.get('/ejs',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${publicPath}/index.ejs`);
});
app.get('/ejs',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${publicPath}/Catalog.ejs`);
});
app.get('/ejs',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${publicPath}/Contacts.ejs`);
});

// New Code
app.get('/ejs', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '../ejs/Catalog.ejs'); 
  });
```

[Директория проекта](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6N4d.png)

Имеется директория проекта в котором есть файлы ejs страниц и именно на них мне нужно ссылаться.

Запуская через Live Server в VSCode у  меня все работает но когда я запускаю сервер от express'а то все ссылки возвращают мне

Cannot GET /Catalog.ejs (либо любой другой файл)

Файл index рабочий ( я менял или добавлял слова на страницу либо менял тайтл и обновлял страницу и все работало) Следовательно я думаю что проблема в том что я не правильно ссылаюсь либо не написал какой либо маршрутизатор ( я читал в интернете и на основе полученной информации пытался воссоздать что-то похожее но мне не помогло

Comment: Вы должны для каждого файла/пути указать свой обработчик, например для выдачи catalog.ejs пишем `app.get('/catalog.ejs',(req,res)`. Еще можно для статических файлов указать каталоги, где будет осуществляться поиск. Как то так делается `app.use(express.static('/publick'))`. [Подробнее о статке](https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html).

Comment: В целом, разница в том, что live server ищет сам запрошенные ресурсы внутри корня сайта автоматически, в то время, как для experss надо все пути задавать "вручную"